# Populating a Spinner in a Fragment using ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer

I use ActionBarSherlock Library to implement a navigation drawer in my app, then I have a main class called MainActivity where the navigation drawer is shown, and inside it I've instantiated all my fragments. I can't populate the spinner of the frament "novopedido" (NovoPedido.java) because the getActivity() method is returning my main class (MainActivity).

In MainActivity.java:`Fragment novopedido = new NovoPedido();`

```
    private void selectItem(int position) {

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Locate Position
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, home);
        break;
    case 1:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, novopedido);
        break;
    case 8:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, configs);
        break;   
    case 10:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, capture);
        break;
    }
    ft.commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);

    // Get the title followed by the position
    setTitle(title[position]);
    // Close drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

In NovoPedido.java

```
btnBuscarProduto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    buscarProduto();                          
                }

              }).start();
        }
    });

void buscarProduto(){
    try{
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101/android/busca.php");
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("busca", edtBuscaProduto.getText().toString().trim())); 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));            
        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);           
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Vazio")){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nada foi encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();             
        }
        else{
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            String[] responseArray = response.split("\\|");
            System.out.println("Itens do response: "+response);
            for (int i =0; i<responseArray.length; i++){
                list.add(responseArray[i]);
                System.out.println("Item Adicionado: "+responseArray[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("responseArray.length: "+responseArray.length);
            System.out.println("responseArray: "+responseArray);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = arrayAdapter;
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            spnProdutos.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            System.out.println("Activity: "+getActivity());
        }
    } catch(NetworkOnMainThreadException e) {
    //  System.out.println("Erro de network: "+e.getMessage());
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Erro: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What else should getActivity() return?

Comment: I think "com.tcc.megustapizzas.NovoPedido" the class that is running and it's returning "com.tcc.megustapizzas.MainActivity", I think that my spinner is not populating because of this

Comment: Using a try/catch after the "for" I got the following exception: "android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."